# Spring CrudRepository, Webservice, return json object with certain String

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

I am pretty new to Spring Boot development and i need some help with a certain case.

I am creating a RESTful webservices with the JPA/Hibernate Spring and the CRUDrepository.(Json format)

I have the following Table Track:

```
    +----+----------+-----------+
    | id |  filename            |
    +----+----------+-----------+
    |  1 |  public/11111/Cool  |
    |  2 |  public/22222/Cool  |
    |  3 |  public/33333/Cool  |
    |  4 |  public/44444/Cool  |
    |  5 |  public/55555/Cool  |
    |  6 |  public/66666/Cool  |
    |  7 |  private/77777/Cool |
    |  8 |  private/88888/Cool |
    |  9 |  private/99999/Cool |
    +----+----------+-----------+
```

I have the Following Entity:

```
@Entity
public class Track{

    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name="filename")
    private String filename;

    public Track() {
        super();
    }

    public Track(int id, String filename) {
        super();
        this.id= id;
        this.filename= filename;
    }

    public int getid() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setid(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getfilename() {
        return dateiName;
    }

    public void setfilename(String filename) {
        this.filename = filename;
    }
}
```

The CRUD:

```
public interface TrackRepository extends CrudRepository<Track, Integer> {

    List<Track> findByid(int id);

}
```

The Controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(path="rest/music")
public class TrackController {

    @Autowired
    private TrackRepository trackRepository;

    @GetMapping(path="/all")
    public @ResponseBody Iterable<Track> getAllTrack() {
        return trackRepository.findAll();
    }

    @GetMapping(path="/id")
    public @ResponseBody Iterable<Track> 
    getTrackById(@RequestParam("id") int id){
        return trackRepository.findByid(id);

    }
    @GetMapping(path="/public")
    public @ResponseBody Iterable<Track> 
    getPublicTrack(){
        return ...working

    }
    @GetMapping(path="/private")
    public @ResponseBody Iterable<Track> 
    getPrivateTrack(){
        return ...working

    }

}
```

So i can get all Track or search them by id.

Now comes my question how can i return all Track where the filme name starts with "public" or "private".

So i get a json response like:

private:

```
[
       {
            "id": 7,
            "filename": "private/77777/Cool"
       }
       {
            "id": 8,
            "filename": "private/88888/Cool"
       }
       {
            "id": 9,
            "filename": "private/99999/Cool"
       }
]
```

I kinda need to filter the filename string and then... i just cant get the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do this using hql

```
  public interface MusicRepository extends CrudRepository<Music, Integer> {

List<Music> findByid(int id);

@Query("Select m from Music m where m.filename like '%private' or m.filename like '%public'")
List<Music> findCustom();
}
```

Comment: it throws following exceptions: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'trackController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'trackRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'trackRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List de.hhn.testing.track.TrackRepository.findCustom()!

Comment: notice that i changed the name from music to "track"

Comment: i also get this exception: Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'trackRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List de.hhn.testing.track.TrackRepository.findCustom()!

Comment: and this one:  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: track is not mapped [Select m from Track m where m.filename like '%private' or m.filename like '%public']

Comment: Select m from Music, Music here is the name of the class, so if you changed it to Music you should change it in the query too, so it becomes Select m from Track